# Redirect Firefox web browser in PHP

Tags: php, html, redirect

How would one block / redirect a web browser from a site in PHP, I have tried using this code,

```
<?php
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
return (stripos($userAgent, 'Firefox') !== FALSE);
?>
```

Is there another way to redirect the browser to another page? Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Output `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` on the browser you want to block; is `Firefox` present? If so how are you using this code?

Comment: @DaveChen then, again, why?????

Comment: @DaveChen so to achieve that you block all firefox users from your site? Not to mention that a bot could mimic any user agent and all headers to perfection then you'd better block all browsers or better... shut the website down

Comment: Blocking firefox browsers is not the answer to stopping malicious bots. FF probably shouldn't be blocked but the issue of why this is necessary hasn't been posted yet... (85% chance there is a better solution)...

Comment: @JulioSoares I will be using it more for redirecting Firefox users to a different page, due to the site not being Firefox friendly. And as well what DaveChen is trying to explain.

Comment: @DaveChen I'm going to be redirecting them to a part of the site that is Firefox friendly. I will not be blocking Firefox from the site as a whole.

Comment: @GrizPwnz Please have all this information in the question beforehand. It's difficult to provide an answer if all the details are in the comments. Using words like "block" instead of "redirect" will bring different answers entirely.

Comment: @DaveChen Sorry for the confusion, I will make sure next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test the user agent and if firefox, redirect.... something like

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (strlen(strstr($agent, 'Firefox')) > 0) {
        header("Location: http://www.google.com:);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely give this a try!